# Got "Excavator" tag for "editing" non-existent old post when I wasn't even on the site - have I been hacked?

Tags: support, bug

I was very confused to get the "Excavator" badge just now:

> Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months. user568458 earned this badge 2 times
>
> Recently awarded to:
>
> 4 mins ago (post deleted or otherwise unavailable)

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/80/excavator?userid=2646

I wasn't actually active on the site at the time I'm supposed to have edited this post - which now doesn't exist?

In fact clicking on this badge notification just now is the first time I've visited this site for several days.

What's going on? Have I been hacked?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a know SE issue, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over

Comment: Or you could have posted that link, which itself was only posted 10 minutes ago, as the answer to the question... Since "it's a network wide bug" is the answer to the question...

Comment: Adding that as an answer would bring no value to the future readers of this site.  This bug is being reported *hundreds* on times as new posts, comments, in chat, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [known bug with badge awarding process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over) that has affected the [awarding of the Marshall & Excavator badges](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/marshal). SE is looking into the issue.

Comment: You're right, I just saw there's a question about it on the main meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over